# Can't Seem to get my program to stop throwing up invalid syntax

Tags: python

I have been trying to write my first game in python, I've tried to keep it as simple as possible but when I run my code it's simply just throwing up a syntax error even though the option I have provided should work. I think it may be an issue with the player choice #1 specifically. I am still having trouble with the logic of it all so please do you best to show me what I am doing wrong so I can become better in the future :-)

```
player = {'name': 'George', 'attack': 10, 'heal': 16, 'health': 100}
monster = {'name': 'Fat Boy Joe', 'attack': 15, 'health': 150}
game_running = True

while game_running == True:
    player_won = False
    monster_won = False
    print('Please Select An Option')
    print('1)Attack')
    print('2)Heal')


    player_choice = input()    
    if player_choice == "1":
        print('Attacking')
        monster['health'] = monster['health'] - player['attack']
        if monster['health'] <= 0:
            player_won = True
        else:
            player['health'] = player['health'] - monster['attack']

    elif player_choice == '2':
        print('Healing')
        player['health'] = player['health'] + player['heal']
        print('player health ', player['health'])

    else:
        print('Invalid input')

    if player_won == True or monster_won == True:
        game_running = False
        if player['health'] <= 0:
            player_won = True
        print('monster health ', monster['health'], 'and player health ', player['health'])
        if player['health'] <= 0:
            print('Congratulations you have won the game!')
        else:
            print('Sorry but the monster A.K.A. Fat Boy Joe won the game this time')
```

What the game is supposed to do-

1. My game is a simple monster vs player game
2. The player attacks the monster and the monster attacks back
3. The player is allowed to heal himself but the monster deals out more damage than the player
4. The code should allow for the player to make two decisions either attack or heal himself but it always throws up invalid syntax when I try to pick one

Here is also a list of thing's that I have tried

- Changing my indents
- Changing the if else elif commands arround to see if that would help

Comment: It would be nice if u could include the error. Went to your code it doesn't have .py extension. Pls include your code in question with proper formatting, that way it is quite helpful.

Comment: @skaul05 sorry if it's not the best formatting but I mistyped it's not a syntax error it's a invalid input from my code so there's something wrong in the logic of the code. I also tried uploading the code directly from pycharm but for some reason it won't upload properly. I tried to create a repository because I thought it would be preferable to just pasting my code here.

Comment: Without seeing the full error message, we can't possibly help.

Comment: include elif statement for `player_choice == '2'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that you were not using `elif` statement in the middle. You have to use `if-elif-else` for checking your `player_choice`

```
player = {'name': 'George', 'attack': 10, 'heal': 16, 'health': 100}
monster = {'name': 'Fat Boy Joe', 'attack': 15, 'health': 150}
game_running = True

while game_running == True:
    player_won = False
    monster_won = False
    print('Please Select An Option')
    print('1)Attack')
    print('2)Heal')
    player_choice = input()
    if player_choice == '1':
        print('Attacking')
        monster['health'] = monster['health'] - player['attack']
        if monster['health'] <= 0:
            player_won = True
        else:
            player['health'] = player['health'] - monster['attack']
    elif player_choice == '2':
        print('Healing')
        player['health'] = player['health'] + player['heal']
        print('player health ', player['health'])
    else:
        print('Invalid input')
    if player_won == True or monster_won == True:
        game_running = False
        if player['health'] <= 0:
            player_won = True
        print('monster health ', monster['health'], 'and player health ', player['health'])
        if player['health'] <= 0:
            print('Congratulations you have won the game!')
        else:
            print('Sorry but the monster A.K.A. Fat Boy Joe won the game this time')
```

Comment: thank you for helping me out here! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @zman Please consider accepting the answer, if my answer helped you